# MediaPlayer force close on mPlayer.start() or .stop() on some devices but not others

Tags: android, media-player

I've got an issue with different devices in an audio recording app I'm working on.  The app works fine for me on my HTC Incredible running 2.3.4 but the other two devices I've had it tested on force closed.  I know one of them crashes when I call .start() on my MediaPlayer and the other when .stop() is called (I think...).  I'm a bit lost on how to troubleshoot this since the code involved is pretty straightforward.  How does one troubleshoot such things on multiple devices especially when those devices aren't on hand?

I did get Logcat output from the case that the app and it mentioned a NullPointerException on mPlayer.start().  How can one device get a NPE but not another on identical code?

Comment: Do you use any hardcoded paths to your media files/folders? E.g. if you hardcode the path to the sdcard *(instead of using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`)* in the URI that you pass to MediaPlayer.create(), it will fail on some devices. Which means that the returned MediaPlayer instance is `null`. Which will throw an NPE when you try to call `start()`. This should be consistent across devices. Just my a shot in the blue, kinda hard to diagnose to be honest.

Comment: I'm using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() for that.  Could be getAbsolutePath() causing trouble?

Comment: No, that should be fine.